# DRBD what is the meaning of warning "nothing to do in stacked mode"

Tags: drbd, warning

We just installed DRBD on one node (the second one is not installed).

After doing

```
drbdadm primary theres
service drbd start
```

everything is ok (resource available) but the following warning message appears

```
WARN: nothing stacked for this host (node01.com), nothing to do in stacked mode!
```

Using drbd 8.4.6, config:

```
global {
        minor-count 1;
        usage-count no;
}

resource theres {
        protocol C;

        on node01.com {
                device /dev/drbd0;
                disk /dev/dxcd0e;
                address 10.10.10.1:7788;
                meta-disk internal;
        }

        on node02.com {
                device /dev/drbd0;      
                disk /dev/dxcd0e;           
                address 10.10.10.2:7788;  
                meta-disk internal;     
        }

        disk {
                on-io-error detach;     
        }

        net {
        }

        syncer {
                rate 80M;               
        }
}
```

This didn't appear before upgrading to that version.

Comment: When you have an three-node setup, the 3rd is called "device stacked". You can see <https://drbd.linbit.com/users-guide/s-three-nodes.html>

Comment: Do I have a 3-nodes setup?

Comment: With the data provided in your config, we have a two-node configuration.

Comment: So the meaning is that since there is only two hosts, drbd does not have to process a stacked device - why the need of a warning in this case? In earlier versions that warning did not appear.